# How to switch records in one table by Sql Command?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have such question for database developers.
I have a table which has two columns, first one is ID, Second one is Year(2002,2003,2004...it is string). I want to update them by switching the records.
In the beginning it is like this.

```
ID    Year
1     2002
2     2003
3     2004
```

I want to switch them and make like this.

```
ID    Year
1     2003
2     2002
3     2004
```

Please pay attention that My Year Column is unique.
So I tried something like this but did not work for me.

```
SqlCeCommand sss = new SqlCeCommand("Update Year Set Year='" + Year1 + "' Where Year='" + Year2 + "'", MainWindow._Conn);
```

Comment: There is nasty SQL injection in your query, and it has other problems due to concatenation as well.

Comment: These values are not coming from inputbox, just selecting from ListBox. Is there still injection there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider setting `id` to the number of years that are smaller or equal:

```
update   YourTable
set      id = 
         (
         select  count(*)
         from    YourTable yt2
         where   yt2.Year <= YourTable.year
         )
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/10848/3/1)